# Adding json array in a specific scope with php

Tags: php, json, forms

I'm trying to add a **JSON** object to existing JSON array with **PHP** and a **HTML** form

my php file :

```
<?php

    $myFile = "someFile";
    $arr_data = array("myArray"); // create empty array

    try
    {
        //Get form data
        $formdata = array(
            'someImage'=> $_POST['someImage'],
            'someName'=> $_POST['someName'],
            'someFolder'=>$_POST['someFolder']
        );

        //Get data from existing json file
        $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

        // converts json data into array
        $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

        // Push user data to array
        array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

        //Convert updated array to JSON
        $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

        //write json data into data.json file
        if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
            echo 'Data successfully saved';
        }
        else 
            echo "error";
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

?>
```

it's working fine but my problem is i want to add this new object in a specific JSON array, and not to create a new object

something like this:

```
{
    "myArray": [
        { 
            "someImage": "imageUrl", 
            "someName": "TEST",
            "someFolder" : "folderName"
        },
        { 
            "someImage": "imageUrl2", 
            "someName": "TEST2",
            "someFolder" : "folderName2"
        }
    ] 
}
```

but this is what I'm getting from the above code :

```
{
    "myArray": [
        {
            "someImage": "imageUrl",
            "someName": "TEST",
            "someFolder": "folderName"
        }
    ],
    "0": {
        "someImage": "TESTIMAGE",
        "someName": "TESTNAME",
        "someFolder": "TESTTEST"
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"JSON array"* or *"JSON object"*. [JSON](http://json.org) is a **text representation** of some data structure (usually an object or an array but a scalar value can also be encoded as JSON). Being text, a JSON can only be stored (in a file, in a database etc) or sent through the network. It has to be decoded in order to get back a data structure similar to the one used to create it and this data structure (be it an array or an object or anything else) **is not** a JSON. Your code handles JSON very well and the question is not related to JSON at all.

Comment: You need to read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: @axiac this is an old question. i just fixed some typos. was it on new questions page ?

Comment: Indeed, it is old. I didn't notice. You updated it 10 minutes ago and SO dutifully displayed it on the "Newest" page (where it show not only the new questions but also those having recent activity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// Push user data to array
   array_push($arr_data['maddahs'],$formdata);
```

It's a multidimensional array, so you need to address the right array, the one inside `$arr_data['maddahs']`.